# Guzzle curl error 18 with Laravel

Tags: php, curl, laravel-4

I have an api and a client that I'm developing, both in laravel and I get that error 18 when I try to connect to the api using guzzle.

In my api controller I have this:

```
public function index()
{
    $users = User::orderBy('username', 'asc');

    return Response::json(array(
        'error' => false,
        'users' => $users->get()->toArray()),
        200
    );

}
```

And if I do curl --user admin@admin.com:password http://myapi.api/api/v1/users

I get the info that I need correctly on my console:

```
 {"error":false,"users":[{"id":"1","firstname":"","lastname":"","username":"admin@admin.com","created_at":"2014-10-17 15:35:10","updated_at":"2014-10-17 15:35:10","client_id":"0","enterprise_id":"0","usertype_id":"0"},{"id":"2","firstname":"","lastname":"","username":"seconduser","created_at":"2014-10-17 15:35:10","updated_at":"2014-10-17 15:35:10","client_id":"0","enterprise_id":"0","usertype_id":"0"}]}
```

The url even works in the browser (I get a popup for authentication and after it I get the same input on the browser). So it's only failing via guzzle.

Now on my client I have Guzzle installed and I'm trying this:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$user='admin@admin.com';
$pass='password';

$res = $client->get('http://myapi.api/api/v1/users', array(
    'auth' =>  array('admin@admin.com', 'password')
));

$users=$res->json();  
$users=$users['users'];
```

And I get the error:

```
[curl] (#18) See http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html for an explanation of cURL errors [url] http://myapi.api/api/v1/users
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Using -v in the command I get:

```
$ curl -v --user admin@admin.com:password http://myapi.api/api/v1/users
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to myapi.api (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'admin@admin.com'
> GET /api/v1/users HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic YWRtaW5AYWRtaW4uY29tOnBhc3N3b3Jk
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
> Host: myapi.api
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Mon, 20 Oct 2014 13:08:56 GMT
* Server Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.8 PHP/5.5.17 mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/0.9.8za DAV/2 mod_perl/2.0.8 Perl/v5.20.0 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.8 PHP/5.5.17 mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/0.9.8za DAV/2 mod_perl/2.0.8 Perl/v5.20.0
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.17
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Set-Cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IjRPMk9TT0ZnZklTMG1uWlFDancyMWc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoic1V1RjA5aVBJdFNLM0JLclNROEE1a0dCeHNEMWhVNFVReTlUOHdidE44WEJzRnB4WFkxdWo0V0ozcXFVSW9LYzZiZzZSSlFCNXNTTjl2Mzh4TlFtTUE9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjhlYzY0YjFkNTQzNjk5ZGMxNDk3YmY4ZjU4YTYzYzM4YzgxZjg1MzlhMWUxNWVjYWE4ZThlMmU0N2RjNWFkZGMifQ%3D%3D; expires=Mon, 20-Oct-2014 15:08:57 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: application/json
<
* Connection #0 to host myapi.api left intact
{"error":false,"users":[{"id":"1","firstname":"","lastname":"","username":"admin@admin.com","created_at":"2014-10-17 15:35:10","updated_at":"2014-10-17 15:35:10","client_id":"0","enterprise_id":"0","usertype_id":"0"},{"id":"2","firstname":"","lastname":"","username":"seconduser","created_at":"2014-10-17 15:35:10","updated_at":"2014-10-17 15:35:10","client_id":"0","enterprise_id":"0","usertype_id":"0"}
```

EDIT: This question is probably too specific and even though I haven't found a solution and have gone a different way with this project because specifications have changed I will leave it here in case it can help someone.

My guess on the answer is as André Daniel suggests in a comment, that the authentication is breaking something and guzzle isn't giving me my original json thus creating the error.

Comment: Error #18 means *CURLE_PARTIAL_FILE - A file transfer was shorter or larger than expected. This happens when the server first reports an expected transfer size, and then delivers data that doesn't match the previously given size*.

Comment: I updated my question with that, André. How can I fix it? I haven't worked much with curl, but this code worked on a very similar project.

Comment: Edited again with that info

Comment: Can you try without basic authentication ? If that still doesn't work, can you try [this version](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=CRG91X29) (which I used to test it on my side, and it worked perfectly) and see if that works on your side ? (of course adapt the URLs to your app)

Answer (score 0):

On your question you said this URL works via the command line:

```
 http://myapi.api/api/v1/users/1
```

But you are calling this URL via guzzle

```
 http://myapi.api/api/v1/users
```

So are you sure the route you are trying to call via guzzle works via the command line?

Comment: both urls should work, one gives one user, the other gives all

Comment: Yes - I know that - but *does* both urls work via console? You are not comparing the same urls, so we cannot be sure if the problem is with guzzle, or your code. Please amend the question to confirm guzzle fails for `http://myapi.api/api/v1/users/1` and the error it gives for *that* url

Comment: Yes, they all work on the console, it was just a typo when copying to make the question

Answer (score 0):

I finally changed the approach as we needed a different authentication method, so this question is no longer relevant to my case.

Comment: Not a proper answer to be accepted. If a try to get your bounty back, it [won't work](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275184/1836314).

Comment: I don't need the bounty. No other proper answers where given, so bounty for no one.

Comment: A proper answer could have been given in the future. If you think a question is only relevant for yourself, better not post it on SO. NRN bye

Comment: I will change the accepted answer if one should come. I just think maybe this question won't really get answered and I can't really delete it. I agree it might not be appropiate for SO in this case. What should I do then, not accept any answer? I'm fine with that too. What's better?

Comment: Your interest proves you're a good SO user, sorry for my early speculation. Well, if you _do feel the need_, rather than posting as an answer and accepting it, just edit the question: add a disclaimer at the beginning, saying that the question is no longer relevant for you, but you leave it there for public utility. Regards

Comment: I'm pleased of that! If you find the time, you may want to move the disclaimer on top (at the very beginning) of the question, and/or emphasize it (e.g. bold style). Goodbye

Answer (score 0):

I know this is pretty old, but here's what I got to work with Guzzle:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$user = 'admin@admin.com';
$pass = 'password';

$res = $client->get('http://myapi.api/api/v1/users', [
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode($user . ":" . $pass),
    ],
]);

$users = $res->json();  
$users = $users['users'];
```

You could even store the authorization data on the Guzzle instance, like this:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode($user . ":" . $pass),
    ],
]);
$user='admin@admin.com';
$pass='password';

$res = $client->get('http://myapi.api/api/v1/users');

$users = $res->json();  
$users = $users['users'];
```